# android branch to a activity programmicaticlly

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to create an intent using a variable, then startactivity using the variable?

Example: The standard method

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);
 startActivity(myIntent);
```

Can a variable activity be used;

```
 String newActivity =  "Main4.class";
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,newActivity);
```

Comment: could you able to run this way?

Answer (score 0):

If you can put your Activity class name as String without the `.class` postfix and with complete package name like this,

`String newActivity =  "org.test.Main4";`

Then I believe you can do this,

```
   try {
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Class.forName(newActivity));

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Try but got a java exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Class type to store a specific class:

```
Class newActivity = BasicActivity.class;
startActivity(new Intent(this, newActivity));
```

And depending on your needs you can check the variable against different classes.

```
Class basicActibity = BasicActivity.class;
if (newActivity == basicActibity)
```